# Dryer Takes Too Long, Cleaned out Vent. What next?

Tags: dryer, laundry

We just cleaned out the dryer vent with a leaf blower like this:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dO9Y5j1uhqk

Unfortunately it still takes over 2 runs to dry a load.  Before we did this, however, we disconnected the tube from the wall and let the tube exhaust into the laundry room (it gets very hot and humid!), and the load was perfectly dry after about 45 min.  So, it seems the problem is indeed in the tubing in the walls.

Any thoughts on what to do next?

Comment: How long is the pipe in the wall? How many bends are in the pipe?

Comment: What's in the section that you disconnected? Are you sure it isn't plugged partially or completely? Have you examined the flap/screen at the end?

Answer (score 2):

If you did everything Jim did & got the same dump & blow-out, then that was an improvement. But, that method doesn't scrub or peel anything off. It just makes a small hole in the center to leave the built-up sides to collapse & fall inward to clog up again. Keep trying the blower periodically & shake & pound on the pipe wherever you can. Otherwise, use a vacuum at both ends or a vacuum in conjunction of an extendable dryer vent brush.